# How can Pixate change styles dynamically in code? (iOS)

Tags: ios, pixate

I am using PixateFreestyle as a pod. I can style views with styleId from the default.css file. I am trying to change the style information on the fly in code. I have tried this:

```
self.view.styleCSS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ background-color : #991199; }"];
[PixateFreestyle updateStylesForAllViews];
```

This has no effect. I have also tried:

```
self.view.styleCSS = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{ background-color : #991199; }"];
[self.view updateStyles];
```

This also has no effect.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

No curly braces in the string, do this instead:

```
self.view.styleCSS = @"background-color: #991199;";
```

There's also a category you can import:

```
#import <PixateFreestyle/NSDictionary+PXCSSEncoding.h>
```

Then you can make the code cleaner with something like this:

```
 self.view.styleCSS = @{ @"background-color": @"#991199",
                         @"color"           : @"red"
                       }.toCSS;
```